# How to refine a mesh in python quickly

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy `array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])`, which is actually a mesh in 1 dimension in my problem. What I want to do is to refine the mesh to get this: `array([0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.2,])`.

The actual array is very large and this procedure costs a lot of time. How to do this quickly (maybe vectorize) in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
(a[:,None] + np.arange(-0.2,0.3,0.1)).ravel() # a is input array
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])  # Input array

In [16]: (a[:,None] + np.arange(-0.2,0.3,0.1)).ravel()
Out[16]: 
array([ 0.8,  0.9,  1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,  2.2,  2.8,
        2.9,  3. ,  3.1,  3.2])
```

Comment: Great! More than half the time of option 3 in Psidom's anwser is saved!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options(python 3):

*Option 1*:

```
np.array([j for i in arr for j in np.arange(i - 0.2, i + 0.25, 0.1)])
# array([ 0.8,  0.9,  1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,  2.2,  2.8,
#         2.9,  3. ,  3.1,  3.2])
```

*Option 2*:

```
np.array([j for x, y in zip(arr - 0.2, arr + 0.25) for j in np.arange(x,y,0.1)])
# array([ 0.8,  0.9,  1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,  2.2,  2.8,
#         2.9,  3. ,  3.1,  3.2])
```

*Option 3*:

```
np.array([arr + i for i in np.arange(-0.2, 0.25, 0.1)]).T.ravel()
# array([ 0.8,  0.9,  1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,  2.2,  2.8,
#         2.9,  3. ,  3.1,  3.2])
```

---

*Timing on a larger array*:

```
arr = np.arange(100000)
arr
# array([    0,     1,     2, ..., 99997, 99998, 99999])

%timeit np.array([j for i in arr for j in np.arange(i-0.2, i+0.25, 0.1)])
# 1 loop, best of 3: 615 ms per loop

%timeit np.array([j for x, y in zip(arr - 0.2, arr + 0.25) for j in np.arange(x,y,0.1)])
# 1 loop, best of 3: 250 ms per loop

%timeit np.array([arr + i for i in np.arange(-0.2, 0.25, 0.1)]).T.ravel()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.93 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hi, I have got a new idea: `(np.tile(np.arange(-0.2, 0.25, 0.1)[None, :], (n, 1)) + arr[:, None]).flatten()`, where `n=100000` in your post.It seems that I avoided a `for` in your option 3, but the performance is more or less the same. Why?

Comment: Nice, that looks a more numpy option. The performance is most likely because the `np.arange(-0.2, 0.25, 0.1` contains only five elements, so the time to loop through it is negligible. If this is a much larger array, you might see a difference.

Comment: Not much difference if I change `np.arange(-0.2, 0.25, 0.1)` to `np.arange(-0.2, 0.25, 0.001)`. Maybe list comprehension is already very efficient.